# TypeScript function whose parameter should accept one of two types

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function whose parameter can be one of two types. The function then may invoke another function. I am, however, getting an error message. You can see the script and a screenshot below. How do I write this function so that it can accept a parameter with one of two types? Thanks!

```
interface A {
  a: string;
  title: string,
}

interface B {
  b: number;
  title: string;
}

const alpha = (data: A) => data.a;

const beta = (data: B) => data.b;

const foo = (data: A | B) => {
  if (data.title === 'a') {
    return alpha(data);  // Message: "Argument type A | B is not assignable to type A"
  }
  if (data.title === 'b') {
    return beta(data);  // Message: "Argument type A | B is not assignable to type B"
  }
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (like casting) on the parameter so the compiler (and IDE) treats it as the appropriate type once you've determined which type it is.

```js
interface A {
  a: string;
  title: string,
}

interface B {
  b: number;
  title: string;
}

const alpha = (data: A) => data.a;

const beta = (data: B) => data.b;

const foo = (data: A | B) => {
  if (data.title === 'a') {
    return alpha(<A>data);
  }
  if (data.title === 'b') {
    return beta(<B>data);
  }
};
```

> Type assertions are a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what I’m doing.” A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but performs no special checking or restructuring of data. It has no runtime impact, and is used purely by the compiler. TypeScript assumes that you, the programmer, have performed any special checks that you need.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that typescript does not know that `title === 'a'` means that the type for data is `a`.  Luckily,  you can provide a more narrow type instead of `string` to help typescript with that.

```
interface A {
  a: string;
  title: 'a' ; // title can now be 'a'  only, not any other string. 
}

interface B {
  b: number;
  title: 'b' ; // title can now be 'b'  only, not any other string. 
}
```

Comment: Indeed, in this case they can just keep their original code.

Answer (score 1):

You need a type guard, something that would tell TS that `A` objects have their title equal to `a`, and `B` objects - to `b`:

```
const isA = (x: A | B): x is A => x.title === 'a';
const isB = (x: A | B): x is B => x.title === 'b';
```

and then:

```
const foo = (data: A | B): any => {
  if (isA(data)) {
    return alpha(data);
  }
  if (isB(data)) {
    return beta(data);
  }
};
```

A better option would be to make your discriminating value (`a` and `b`) a type rather than a string:

```
interface A1 {
  a: string;
  title: 'a',
}

interface B1 {
  b: number;
  title: 'b';
}
```

Then you can simply use `switch`, which acts as type guard:

```
const foo1 = (data: A1 | B1): any => {
  switch (data.title) {
    case 'a': return alpha(data);
    case 'b': return beta(data);
  }
};
```

[Docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions)

[PG](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgLmQGcwpQBzAbh2TGDABsJCSyRyAaLAXyy1EixEKAEKYaAI0IgArgFsJ0arjqNmxUhWq8sCAPYgSyYEXQBeZAAoAHoXQAfZCICUha8aJpkZgHzJrAHSqTN5mFgDkcOHU+oZgHmIWNnbIji5uHk7efoHBKGEREtF8ugZGcAwADgAWcN5WACZwYARoztnITS0BcNSlcciKLfWWXa0uHWMBEn2xRjB6eiNjKWmueCAAnh3YuMAwViaoo81wzu27uMhQEGAyUCB4VbUnLc7KyLx7B5YmIq9nC40XA3O4PQa3OAA940XjcPr8cDQeBINAARnEuFarC0NDyhEi4S4OgEyOETgxlykyFkCiUePoTAJRW0fDm8QWegxSRW6NSFPWcC2OxoRAA7vQENVGqcgoyIECrsgEHAiChCYRQfdHhUalCxjClSq1chwkVNbdtRCWtCPnC+kA)

Comment: This seems too verbose. You can just adjust the typings to use the more narrow type 'a' instead of 'string' to achieve this without checking explicitly.

Comment: @pascalpuetz: isn't that what I wrote in the second snippet ("a better option")?

Comment: Seems I've missed that one, sorry. That is exactly what I meant, ignore my previous comment :)

Answer (score -9):

Please use `any`.

```
const foo = (data: any) => {
  if (data.title === 'a' && checkA(data)) {
    return alpha(data);
  }
  if (data.title === 'b' && checkB(data)) {
    return beta(data);
  }
};
```

And check interface type by creating your own function.

```
function checkA(obj: any) {
    return 'a' in obj;
}
function checkB(obj: any) {
    return 'b' in obj;
}
```

Comment: Using `any` does indeed work, but it is a bad practice. You practically lose all type safety - which is exactly what typescript is NOT meant for.

Comment: This defeats the entire point of using typescript. Never use `any` unless it's an absolute last resort, and even then you are probably doing something weird.